# ORACLE SQL ORDER BY

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by

How would I go about ordering by the last three letters of a name?

For example:

Ashley

Julia

Belvet

ley > lia > vet

Also, how would I go about doing a secondary sort by ID if the last three letters are the same (Bobby, Robby...)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your first question:

```
ORDER BY SUBSTR(name, -3)
```

For your second question:

```
ORDER BY SUBSTR(name, -3), id
```